# Setup notification when certain method called at runtime

Tags: c#

I feel awkward for asking this, but still.

I have a class `Foo` that's being imported from dll and cannot be modified. There is a method `Bar` which being called from the inside of `Foo` and from other places too.

```
    /* All this is placed inside a dll */

    public class Foo
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
            // does important stuff
        }
    }

    // there are several classes that use Foo.Bar in similar manner
    public sealed class FooBar
    {
        private readonly Foo _foo;

        public FooBar()
        {
            _foo = new Foo();
            ImportantInitialization();
        }

        private void ImportantInitialization()
        {
            // I can't modify code here
            _foo.Bar();
        }
    }
```

I need to know when `Bar` is called (or, which would be better, when the execution of `Bar` is over).

Is there a way to create some sort of event for that purpose? Using `Reflection`, perhaps?

Comment: May be you will try to inherit from `Foo` and write your wrapper for `Bar` with calling event?

Comment: If you can't change *any* code, a profiler is your only option. Profilers can rewrite methods at runtime.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I thought of that, and, to be honest, that's the last thing I would like to do. There is a lot of places from which this method should be called, and there are plenty of ways to mess up passing derived class, 'cause that would require A LOT of `reflection`

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Beyond all information available online on profilers, no. In particular, actually using the profiler APIs is a highly nontrivial task that requires proficiency with unmanaged code, and is not for the faint of heart. Also, you cannot (or rather should not) integrate that with the running code itself -- you could use it to debug/trace code, but you can't use it to execute some code within the application itself whenever `Bar()` is called. If that is your goal, look at solutions like IL rewriters a la PostSharp.

Comment: Are the classes using Foo in places you can change? Just wondering if you could create a wrapper around Foo and have all requests go through that and then you can put any code you want into your wrapper...

Comment: @Chris no, the problem is that I can't reach all the places from which `Foo.Bar` is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below, that should enable you to achieve your goal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479302/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-learn-step-by-step-and

Comment: Please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259)

Comment: That's an interesting paradigm, but from what I understood from your link, I don't think I can apply it to solve my current problem.